# How to remove wrapper when rendering page region?

Tags: 7, theming

```
 $sidebar_second = render($page['sidebar_second']); print $sidebar_second;
```

generate by default

```
 <div class="region region-sidebar-second sidebar">
     <div class="region-inner clearfix">   </div>
 </div>
```

How can i remove these wrappers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a copy, or edit the existing copy, of the core (or your theme/sub-theme's) [region.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!region.tpl.php/7) file, to your active theme. You can change the wrapping markup to whatever you like in there.

Clear the cache, and you're done.